# What is meaning when _JAVA_OPTIONS system variable value is given -Xmx512M?

Tags: java, cordova, system-variable

I am using windows 7 32 bit machine. I was building a cordova project on it and while building it was giving an error as

> "Error occurred during initialization of VM".

This got solved when i defined system variable for `_JAVA_OPTIONS` and gave value as `-Xmx512M`.

What extra information does this value provide to build that it allows build successfully.

Thanks.

Comment: It's giving 512MB of memory for Java to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms). 
`mx` specifies the maximum memory for your java process. It's weird that java didn't start with the default value, usually it happens if you set it to something too big for the physical memory of your machine.